# about the pcpu_fit_in_area function, why "only allocate from already populated region"?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am reading the percpu source code of linux-4.1.
The pcpu_alloc function calls the pcpu_alloc_area function to allocate memory for percpu  data, pcpu_alloc_area returns the start address of this memory. pcpu_alloc function is as  bellow:

```
static void __percpu *pcpu_alloc(size_t size, size_t align, bool  reserved,
             gfp_t gfp)
{
...

bool is_atomic = (gfp & GFP_KERNEL) != GFP_KERNEL;

if (reserved && pcpu_reserved_chunk) {

...

    off = pcpu_alloc_area(chunk, size, align, is_atomic,
                  &occ_pages);

...

}

...
}
```

Then the pcpu_alloc_area function calls pcpu_fit_in_area function to get the memory page in  the pcpu_chunk->map. pcpu_alloc_area function is as bellow:

```
static int pcpu_alloc_area(struct pcpu_chunk *chunk, int size, int align,
           bool pop_only, int *occ_pages_p)
{
...

for (i = chunk->first_free, p = chunk->map + i; i < chunk->map_used; i++, p++) {

    ...

    head = pcpu_fit_in_area(chunk, off, this_size, size, align,
                pop_only);
    ...
}

...

}
```

The pcpu_fit_in_area function is as below:

```
static int pcpu_fit_in_area(struct pcpu_chunk *chunk, int off, int this_size,
            int size, int align, bool pop_only)
{
int cand_off = off;

while (true) {
    int head = ALIGN(cand_off, align) - off;
    int page_start, page_end, rs, re;

    if (this_size < head + size)
        return -1;

    if (!pop_only)
        return head;

    page_start = PFN_DOWN(head + off);
    page_end = PFN_UP(head + off + size);

    rs = page_start;
    pcpu_next_unpop(chunk, &rs, &re, PFN_UP(off + this_size));
    if (rs >= page_end)
        return head;
    cand_off = re * PAGE_SIZE;
}
}

static void __maybe_unused pcpu_next_unpop(struct pcpu_chunk *chunk,
                   int *rs, int *re, int end)
{
*rs = find_next_zero_bit(chunk->populated, end, *rs);
*re = find_next_bit(chunk->populated, end, *rs + 1);
}
```

When the gfp parameter of pcpu_alloc function is GFP_KERNEL, I can understand how all these  functions work. But when this gfp parameter is not GFP_KERNEL, the is_atomic is true, and  then the parameter pop_only of function pcpu_fit_in_area is true. Then the pcpu_fit_in_area  function will return an area which is allocated, because the chunk->populated is all 1  within the result area.
When one bit of chunk->populated set 1 means the corresponding page is used? So why  allocate a memory which is in use?
I'm really confused that the note of pcpu_alloc_area function and pcpu_fit_in_area function  said when the pop_only is true, it allocate only from the populated area, why allocate from  populated area?
Am I misunderstand something?
I am really want to know the answer, thank you!

Comment: Please any common about the question